# Splitting a List and removing corresponding elements in Python

Tags: python, list, nlp, concatenation

I have a List of Parts of Speech tagged words (each element is in the format of "word|tag") and I am trying to find a way to delete the corresponding "tag" after I delete a certain "word." More specifically, my algorithm can only deal with the "word" portion of each element, so I first split my current "word"|"tag" list into two separate lists of words and tags. After I remove certain unnecessary words from the Words list though, I want to concatenate the corresponding tags. How can I effectively delete the corresponding tag from a different list? Or is there a better way to do this? I tried running my cleaning algorithm with the tagged words initially, but couldn't find a way to ignore the tags from each word.

My issue may be more clear by showing my code:

```
my_list = ['I|PN', 'am|V', 'very|ADV', 'happy|ADJ']

tags = []
words = []
for i, x in enumerate(my_list):
    front, mid, end = x.partition('|')
    words.append(front)
    tags.append(mid+end)
```

Current Output (after I run the words list through my cleaning algorithm):

```
words = ['I', 'very', 'happy']
tags = ['PN', 'V', 'ADV', 'ADJ']
```

Clearly, I can not concatenate these lists element-wise anymore because I did not delete the corresponding tag from the removed word.

Desired Output:

```
words = ['I', 'very', 'happy']
tags = ['PN', 'ADV', 'ADJ']
```

How can I achieve the above output?

Comment: you word cleaning algorithm could work on the word/tag couple (using only the word) and cleaning the couple. After that you create your lists (or don't: never assoicate data by index on modern languages, this isn't FORTRAN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you follow this method:

1. Split your input into tuples of (word, tag)
2. Filter the list of tuples based on your needs
3. Convert the remaining list of tuples into two lists of words / tags

Here is an untested implementation:

```
word_list = ['I|PN', 'am|V', 'very|ADV', 'happy|ADJ']

def my_word_filter(pair):
    word, tag = pair
    # ... your word removal logic here. Return True if the word is OK,
    # or false if you want it deleted. For example:
    return word != 'am'

word_pairs = filter(my_word_filter, [w.split('|') for w in word_list])
words, tags = zip(*word_pairs)

# Now do whatever you want from the corresponding lists of words, tags
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try python dictionary ?

```
my_list={"I":"PN","am":"V","very":"ADV","happy":"ADJ"}
del my_list["am"]
print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
my_list={"I":"PN","very":"ADV","happy":"ADJ"}
```

Comment: This won't work because it loses ordering information and will have problems when the same word appears twice in a sentence.